# Is there a direct way to write from Glue job to Glue catalog instead of writing to S3 and running the Glue crawler to populate the Glue catalog

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue

I have a Glue job, the output of which is to be accessed using Athena queries. I know that one way to do this is to write to S3 from the Glue job, and then create a crawler which will populate the output on the Glue Catalog and then this would be available on Athena.

Is there a direct way using which the Glue job can directly write to the Glue catalog instead of writing to S3 and then running the glue crawler, or the above approach is the best way to do it?

I checked a related question but could not find the answer to this:

[AWS glue job (Pyspark) to AWS glue data catalog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72476769/aws-glue-job-pyspark-to-aws-glue-data-catalog)

Thanks